# Matrix Chain Rule Derivative Question

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

[Matrix Partial Derivative and Chain Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnt7l.png)

I don't know how the partial derivative is taken here, and was wondering if all of the steps can be spelled out. The image is linked.

Specific points of confusion are:

1. Why $V_j^T x$ is taken inside $g'$ -- I know that we're dealing with the jth row of the $V$ matrix, but once we've identified the jth row, why is it necessary to transpose? I thought $V_j$ is a row and $x \in \R^n$
2. Why is $V_{ji}$ multiplied to the end of the expression, instead of $V_{ji}^T$? I thought the derivative of $Vx$ is $V^T$

Comment: Hard to say without knowing how $V_j$ is defined.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}$Define the following vectors
$$\eqalign{
w  &= Vx, \qquad h &= g(w), \qquad h' &= g'(w) \\
}$$
where $g$ is a scalar function, $g'$ is its derivative, and the vectors $(h,h')$ are the result of applying these scalar functions element-wise to the $w$ vector.
Because of the element-wise nature of the functions, the differential of $h$ requires a Hadamard (element-wise) product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
dh &= h'\odot dw \\
   &= {\rm Diag}(h')\, dw \\
   &= H'\, dw \\
}$$
The last line uses the well known "trick" of replacing a Hadamard product by a diagonal matrix.

With the above notation, calculating the gradient of $h$ with respect to $x$ is almost trivial.
$$\eqalign{
dh &= H'\,\c{dw} \;=\; H'\,\c{V\,dx} \\
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} &= H'\,V \;\;\doteq\;\; Dh(x) \\
  &= \big(h'{\tt1}^T\big)\odot V &\quad\big({\rm Hadamard\,equivalent}\big) \\
}$$
The answer given in your book is the author's (poor) attempt to write this result using neither the `Diag()` function nor the Hadamard product.